# How to rename values by frequency in R

Tags: r, rename, frequency

I am making several graphs based on the clustering data from DAPC.  I need the colors to be the same across all the graphs, and I'd like to use specific colors for the largest groups.  The important thing for this question, is I get a data set from DAPC like this:

```
my_df <- data.frame(
  ID = c(1:10),
  Group = c("a", "b", "b", "c", "a", "b", "a", "b", "b", "c")
)

> my_df

ID  Group
1   a           
2   b           
3   b           
4   c           
5   a           
6   b           
7   a           
8   b           
9   b           
10  c
```

I know how to find the group with the most members like this:

```
freqs <- table(my_df$Group)
freqs <- freqs[order(freqs, decreasing = TRUE)]

>freqs
b a c 
5 3 2
```

Is there a way to change the values based on their frequency?  Each time I rerun DAPC, it changes the groups, so I'd like to write code that does this automatically instead of having to redo it manually.  Here's how I'd like the dataframe to be changed:

```
> my_df                          > my_new_df
ID  Group                        ID  Group
1   a                             1  '2nd'
2   b                             2  '1st'          
3   b                             3  '1st'          
4   c                             4  '3rd'          
5   a                             5  '2nd'          
6   b                             6  '1st'          
7   a                             7  '2nd'          
8   b                             8  '1st'          
9   b                             9  '1st'          
10  c                             10 '3rd'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `ave` and create a `factor` out of it with the corresponding `labels=`. To avoid hard-coding, define the labels in a vector `lb` beforehand.

```
lb <- c("1st", "2nd", "3rd", paste0(4:10, "th"))

with(my_df, factor(as.numeric(ave(as.character(Group), as.character(Group), FUN=table)),
       labels=rev(lb[1:length(unique(table(Group)))])))
#  [1] 2nd 1st 1st 3rd 2nd 1st 2nd 1st 1st 3rd
# Levels: 3rd 2nd 1st
```

To convert more columns like this, use `sapply`.

```
sapply(my_df[selected.columns], function(x) {
  factor(as.numeric(ave(as.character(x), as.character(x), FUN=table)),
         labels=rev(lb[1:length(unique(table(x)))]))
})
```

Comment: This works a treat for numeric groups, but if Group is a factor, I get this Error: ```invalid factor level, NA generated number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length Error in factor(with(my_df2, ave(Group, Group, FUN = table)), labels = c("3rd",  : 
  invalid 'labels'; length 3 should be 1 or 0 ```                                   Instead I found this workaround            ```freqs <- table(my_df$Group)
freqs <- freqs[order(freqs, decreasing = TRUE)]
my_df$Group2 <- factor(my_df$Group, levels = names(freqs), labels = c("1st", "2nd", "3rd")) ```      Thank you so much!

Comment: @ZDinges You're right, in R version 4.0.2 `data.frame()` no longer gives factors so I didn't know (to share data better always use `dput`, which also copies the actual structure of your data). I adapted the code to work with characters as well as with factors. Also you may construct the labels in an automated way, see edit!

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this:

```
my_df %>% left_join(my_df %>% group_by(Group) %>% summarise(N=n())) %>%
  arrange(desc(N)) %>% select(-N)

   ID Group
1   2     B
2   3     B
3   6     B
4   8     B
5   9     B
6   1     A
7   5     A
8   7     A
9   4     C
10 10     C
```

**Update**

This can be useful. I hope this helps.

```
my_df %>% left_join(my_df %>% group_by(Group) %>% summarise(N=n()) %>% arrange(desc(N)) %>%
                      bind_cols(my_df %>% select(Group) %>% distinct() %>% rename(key=Group)) %>%
                      rename(NewGroup=Group,Group=key)) %>%
  select(-c(Group,N)) %>% rename(Group=NewGroup)

   ID Group
1   1     B
2   2     A
3   3     A
4   4     C
5   5     B
6   6     A
7   7     B
8   8     A
9   9     A
10 10     C
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I am trying to edit the values, such that "B" would become "A", since it is the most common.  I will edit my question so it is more clear.

Comment: @ZDinges I have updated the answer with what you need. I hope this helps :) !